# How to create a new variable that tells us if the value in a given column is unique or not?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on the titanic dataset and figured that determining if a ticket is unique or not might be predictive. I've written some code below that tells us if the value is unique or not but I have a feeling that there is a much cleaner way of doing this.

```
 import pandas as pd
dummy_data = pd.DataFrame({"Ticket" : ['A','A','B','B','C','D']
                     })

dummy_data
counts = dummy_data['Ticket'].value_counts()
a = counts[counts>1] 
b=a.reset_index(name='Quantity')
b = b.rename(columns={'index': 'Tickets'})
b
dummy_data['Ticket_multiple'] = np.where(dummy_data['Ticket'].isin(b['Tickets']),1,0)
dummy_data.head(10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False`:

> Parameters: keep{‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default ‘first’ :
> *Method to handle dropping duplicates*:
>
> - ‘first’ : Mark duplicates as True except for the first occurrence.
> - ‘last’ : Mark duplicates as True except for the last occurrence.
> - **False : Mark all duplicates as True.**

```
dummy_data['Ticket_multiple'] = dummy_data["Ticket"].duplicated(keep=False).astype(int)
```

​
Output :

```
print(dummy_data)

  Ticket  Ticket_multiple
0      A                1
1      A                1
2      B                1
3      B                1
4      C                0
5      D                0
```

Update :

If you need to consider a value duplicated only if it occurs (`>N`) times, use this :

```
#------------------------------------------------ added this value
#                                               ˅
dummy_data = pd.DataFrame({"Ticket" : ['A','A','A','B','B','C','D']})
​
N = 2 #threshold

m = dummy_data.groupby("Ticket").transform("size").gt(N)

dummy_data["Ticket_multiple (threshold)"] = m.astype(int)

print(dummy_data)
  Ticket  Ticket_multiple  Ticket_multiple (threshold)
0      A                1                            1
1      A                1                            1
2      A                1                            1
3      B                1                            0
4      B                1                            0
5      C                0                            0
6      D                0                            0
```

Comment: I guess it doesn't get any shorter than that? :) Althought my method will allow you to set a duplication threshold so to speak

Comment: Fair enough! I added an equivalent to your threshold approach. Happy coding ;)